# Algorithm for printing all possible 8 digit numbers

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, time-complexity

Do an algorithm for printing all possible 8 digit numbers requires 8 for loops? i.e 10 to power n time complexity. Is there a way I can reduce the number of loops?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can reduce the number of loops?

Yes:

```
printf("00000000\n");
printf("00000001\n");
printf("00000002\n");
printf("00000003\n");
....
```

No loops.  Just a lot of typing.

Comment: lol, smart answer actually.I hope it is only irony

Comment: No need to type it all, you can use a loop to generate the code.

Answer (score 1):

let's try the single loop

```
int i;
for (i = 10000000; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

(assuming you mean decimal representation, c language, and numbers starting with nonzero digit)

If you want to print all the numbers, you won't get any algorithm for speeding up.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to reduce the complexity. To generate 10^n outputs you need to iterate 10^n times.

Comment: That's a mighty handsome picture, Ransom.

Comment: @G.Bach, thanks. That's a look I did for Halloween 2011, I'm almost embarrassed now to put up a more accurate portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-codish...

```
for val in (10000000..99999999)
    display val
```

What makes you think you need 8 loops?

Comment: If there are some limitations like if a number starts with 4 then 4 must not repeat in the entire loop. like 4804123566 is not a valid number. and may be some more conditions like this.

Comment: and your logic also has the same complexity as I mentioned above.

Comment: That's a ridiculous comment.  Your question states you want "all possible numbers".  However, given the processing required to display an integer you would be better off with the 8 loop approach...  Except you can implement that using recursion or a single loop with a stack.  This is better than keeping 8 loop variables, and you can easily implement special rules like you mentioned.